# Find the PDF of $Y=\log|X|$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have a feeling that this pdf does not exist but I am unsure of my solution thus far.

$Y=\log|X|$

$$F_{Y}(y) = {\Bbb P} \left( Y \leq y \right) = {\Bbb P} \left( \ln|X| \leq y\right) = {\Bbb P} \left(e^{\ln|X|}\leq e^y\right) = {\Bbb P} \left(|X|\leq e^y\right)$$

so I think that means:

$F_{X}(e^y)= e^y, x>0$ and $-e^y, x<0$

So the pdf of $Y=f_{Y}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_{X}(e^y)=e^y, x>0$ and $-e^y, x<0$

If $X\sim N(0,1)$ then

$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}, 0<X<1$

But when $0<X<1$ then

$ DNE < \ln|X| < 0$

Also when I tried to graph $\ln|X|$ on desmos it shows an error.

Comment: "$=e^y$ if  $x>0.$" What is $x?$

Comment: $P(|X|\leq e^y)=F_X(e^y)-F_X(-e^y).$

Comment: So $$f_y(y)=e^y\left(f_X(e^y)+f_X(-e^{y})\right)=2e^y f_X(e^y).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track.  You should continue your calculation (remove the absolute value operation!) as follows: for $y \in \mathbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
F_Y(y) &= P[|X| \leq e^y] = P[-e^y \leq X \leq e^y] = \Phi(e^y) - \Phi(-e^y) 
= 2\Phi(e^y) - 1, 
\end{align}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the distribution function of $X \sim N(0, 1)$.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) = F_Y'(y) = 2\phi(e^y)e^y = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}e^{2y} + y}, \quad y \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
is the pdf of $Y$.

Comment: wow, so simple. thank you. i should've thought about $X\sim N(0,1)$ earlier in the problem

Comment: Distribution function? Or cumulative distribution function?

Comment: @Zhanxiong actually I am a little confused how you went from $2\phi(e^y)e^y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-1/2e^{2y}+y}$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo They are the same thing.  In advanced probability, "distribution function" is more frequently used.  See, e.g., Section 14 of *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley.

Comment: @user130306 $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$.  Can you plug in $x = e^y$ and do the simplification?

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes thank you.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Why assume that the reader has read the same books you have? Why assume that the reader is interested in advanced probability?  Why not make it accessible to everyone who has been exposed to elementary probability?